# Case/Break and '{' in my function

Tags: c, break

I'm working on my latest new function. Any explanations would be great since I'm new to programming. I couldn't figure out how to fix this because the errors I got are:
18 syntax error before '{' token

20 case label not within a switch statement

21 (same as above)

22 (same as above)

23 `default' label not within a switch statement

29 [Warning] `return' with a value, in function returning void

32 [Warning] assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

34 [Warning] `return' with a value, in function returning void

```
void moveCar(char board[], char vehicle, char direction, int distance)
{
     int i;
     int position, newPosition;
     int offset;
     for (i = 0; i < size; i++) //the main loop for the vehicles and user's input
     {
         if(isalpha(vehicle))//vehicles for all letters but 'x'
         { 
             if(board[i] == vehicle)//vehicles on board
             {
                  swtich(direction)
                  {
                         case 'r': offset = 1; break;
                         case 'l': offset = -1; break;
                         case 'u': offset = -8; break;
                         case 'd': offset = 8; break;
                         default: printf("invalid direction"); break;

                         newPosition = position + offset; 
                         if(newPosition != '.')
                         {
                                         printf("invalid move.");
                                         return 0;
                         }

                         board = '.';
                         board[newPosition] = vehicle; 
                         return 1;
                   }      
               }
          }
}
```

Comment: Close the switch after the `default` case.

Comment: You have a typo on `swtich`. Needs to be `switch`

Comment: As @ElliottFrisch said, everything after the default case needs to be moved out of the switch -- or needs to be moved before the default case's break, if you intended it to be part of that case.

Comment: It looks like you've edited your question to correct the errors you were asking about. Please don't do that; it makes the question useless to future readers and invalidates the accepted answer. I'm going to roll back your latest edit. (It will still be in the edit history if you want to apply some of it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a typo of Switch as Swtich, the compiler won't recognize it, and the case statements will fail to compile.

Additionally you close your switch statement too early. If you want those commands to execute only in default move them before the break. If you want them to execute for every case move them outside of the switch statement entirely